# WIX: Run msi from mapped network drive

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, network-drive, mapped-drive

I've created msi package with deferred Custom Action:

```
<CustomAction Id="TestTxt" BinaryKey="MyDLL" DllEntry="TestTxt" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="SetTestTxt" Property="TestTxt" Value="[SourceDir]test.txt" />
```

This CA reads the content of test.txt file placed next to the msi.

The installation works fine from local drive and from network path,
BUT when I tried to run it from mapped network drive the CA couldn't find the file test.txt.
I get System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Exception...

Do you have an ideas of what can be the problem and how can I fix it?
thanks!

Comment: SourceDir should be set correctly for mapped drives. You can try creating an installation log to see what value it has for a mapped network drive.

Comment: The SourceDir is correct. In the log of the CustomAction I can see that the missing file is M:\test.txt (M is the mapped drive)...

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be that the msi is run with elevated privileges, and in this case network-mapped drives are not available to the process (see [KB 937624](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624)). Workaround in the KB implies registry editing and computer restart, so there's no simple solution coming to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I'm running the installation on XP, I tried to add the registry key and it didn't help...

Comment: Is your account admin account? You can also run the installer under Process Monitor to have more info.